# How to save functions in localStorage API HTML5

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am trying to save an array in `localStorage` but it contains functions (called promise) in an object of the array, but the problem appears when I convert array to string using `JSON.stringify`, apparently all functions are removed and when I parse string to `JSON Object` it comes without methods.

```js
/* Example code */

var storage = {
 getListUsers: function(){
  return {
   name: 'name',
   age: 'age'
  }
 },
 active: true,
 data: []
}

var convert = JSON.stringify(storage);
localStorage.setItem('data', convert);
```

Best regards.

Comment: Use the optional second argument to `JSON.stringify`, the `replacer` function - and the optional second argument to `JSON.parse`, the `reviver` function - though it's going to be a bit of a challenge

Comment: *"it contains functions (called promise)"* - Are you talking about promises that are in your `storage.data` array? (I.e., promises not actually shown in the question?)

Comment: I would separate logic from data and not store functions in local storage. Makes it difficult to upgrade the version of your code down the road for starters when you have chunks of code scattered in people's browsers. Why not add the function (via extend or some other method) after the object has been rehydrated from localStorage?

Comment: If, as nnnnnn pointed out, some of the data is a Promise, then, a) a Promise isn't a function, and b) the fix is possibly knowing how to deal with asynchronous code - saving a "Promise" is never going to work, because you can't save a working Promise as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Few observations :**

- Functions don't exist in `JSON`. Look into the official document [json.org](http://json.org).
- A value can be a `string` in double quotes, or a `number`, or `true` or `false` or `null`, or an `object` or an `array` but **`not a method`**.
- Why method inside an JSON Object ? Methods is basically used to manipulate the data. You can work with data outside of the JSON object as well.

You can use `JSON.stringify` replacer function to convert the function into string while converting to JSON string.

**DEMO**

```js
var storage = {
 getListUsers: function() {
  return {
   name: 'name',
   age: 'age'
  }
 },
 active: true,
 data: []
}

var json = JSON.stringify(storage, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return value.toString();
  } else {
    return value;
  }
});

console.log(json);
```

Comment: How to re-convert this string to a function as it before ?

Comment: To convert it again to function use JSON.parse then use eval
something like that 
 var storage = JSON.parse(storage);
   storage.getListUsers = eval("(" + storage.getListUsers + ")");

Answer (score 0):

You can set the JavaScript which should be set at `localStorage` as `.textContent` of a `<script>` element, get the `.textContent` of the element to set at `localStorage`. You can then set the same text at a different `<script>` element or convert the text to a `data URI` which can be posted to other browsing contexts or a server.

```
<script id="storage">
/* Example code */

var storage = {
  getListUsers: function() {
    return {
      name: 'name',
      age: 'age'
    }
  },
  active: true,
  data: []
}
</script>
<script>
var convert = document.getElementById("storage");

localStorage.setItem("data", convert.textContent);

console.log(localStorage.getItem("data"));    
</script>
```